# Hide output of add_settings_field()

Tags: settings-api

The output of the settings API's function `add_settings_field()` is this:

```
<tr>
 <th scope="row">Your title</th>
 <td> Your field output </td>
</tr>
```

I know I can't change the way it's output, but I was wondering if there is a way I can put a `display:none;` on the `<tr>` with PHP? I don't want to do it with Javascript because then there is a flash of unstyled content.

Basically, I want a way to hide a row that's output via `add_settings_field()`, because I need it on the frontend - but later on in my flow.

Comment: Plenty of answers already but I don't think I understand. [`add_settings_field()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field#Return_Values) doesn't return/output anything, so not sure what you are doing...

Answer (score 2):

You can hide it using jQuery which will be inserted in the `wp-admin` header:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_239421_hide_section' );
function wpse_239421_hide_section() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('[scope=row]').closest('tr').hide();
        } );
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

This will remove the closet `tr` bases on the `scope=row`.

Comment: I know I can use jQuery, but as clearly stated in my question, I don't want to use Javascript because there's a flash. Until the document is ready, I can see the HTML and then all of a sudden, it disappears.

Answer (score 1):

The sixth parameter (`$args`) of the `add_settings_field` function can contain a `class` value that will be added to the `<tr>`.

You can use this with the built-in admin css class `.hidden`

```php
add_settings_field(
    'field_id',
    'Useless Field Label',
    'render_hidden_field_function',
    'some_settings_page',
    'a_section_slug',
    [
        'class' => 'hidden'
    ]
);
```

Comment: This would hide the input field, but not the entire `tr` including the field label.

Answer (score 0):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.my_add_settings_field_class').find('[scope=row]').hide();  
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you explain why do you think it will solve the problem?

Comment: This only removes the first row.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_settings_field(
    'myprefix_setting-id',
    'This is the setting title',
    'myprefix_setting_callback_function',
    'general',
    'default'',
     array('class' => 'hidden')
);
```

That should/must do the job. Just add the extra arguments "class" used when outputting the field.

Comment: Hi - if you want to take ownership of this with your new account, see the [merging accounts help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Editing it won't do that.

Comment: Your answer looks identical to already given.